# is there a way to comment in json with an editor through comment file

Tags: json

At the comapny we force designers to work with some json, but that can't have comments. They usually use sublime. Is there any plugin or something what wouldinclude comment like things from another file into the json they're editing? Oter editor can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although after adding javascript-like comments this would be not valid JSON it would still be handled by at least few editors. This can be used internally and I think it may be more practical than keeping two separate files. If you need to use this file then reformat it using compact formatting - this would reduce file size and remove comments as well making it valid JSON again (alternatively parse without collecting comments and print using styled writer if size does not matter).